# What is the highest probability

Tags: probability-distributions

At a faculty the probability of seeing a person greater than 190cm is 12%. From a class of $24$ people, is it more reliable to meet $2$ people above $190cm$ or $4$ people above $190cm$?

I dont undersand. Consider that the solution may be related to any distribution (Binomial or Poisson). Help me please to solve. Thanky very much for my hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a binomial distribution for $p=0,12$ and $n=24$:

[image]

Comment: $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, what is k=? please

Comment: $k$ is a number of sucsseses. It runs from 0 to 24. You are interested what is happening if $k=2$ and $k=4$.

Comment: Case 1 :$\frac{24!}{2!(22)!}0.12^2(0.88)^{22}$;                                                     Case 2 :$\frac{24!}{4!(20)!}0.12^4(0.88)^{20}$;

Comment: Yes, and a "graph" of this function is drawn in the answer.

Comment: can you give me any other explanation about the picture that is unclear, you were very clear about the example

Comment: can i ask you for another example, or will i have to post it, you made the example very clear, you are extraordinary

Comment: It is a graph of function $f(k) = {24\choose k}0,12^k\cdot 0,88^{24-k}$ where $k$ runs from $0$ to $24$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106121/discussion-between-madrit-zhaku-and-aqua).